# How to install snmplib module in micropython running over an ESP8266?

Tags: python, iot, esp8266, micropython

I want to run a code which sends email alerts upon meeting certain condition at its GPIO pins. For this I tried to import smtplib, but I am getting the error as shown in the code section. Is there any way around? OR Am I missing something? Please help.

I tried installing smtplib by providing internet access to esp8266. I used pip, upip to install but noting seems working.

> > > import smtplib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: no module named 'smtplib'
> > >
> > > pip install smtplib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >       upip install smtplib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Do you definitely have upip? [Not all ESP8266 builds do](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html#requirements).

Comment: i could import upip successfully , but cannot install smtplib. Any idea?

Comment: Getting this error:
=== import upip
=== upip.install("smtplib")
=== 
Installing to: /lib/
ssl_handshake_status: -70
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "upip.py", line 205, in install
  File "upip.py", line 195, in install
  File "upip.py", line 152, in install_pkg
  File "upip.py", line 141, in get_pkg_metadata
  File "upip.py", line 117, in url_open
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO

Comment: First of all that looks like a connection problem. Can you confirm that the ESP8266 can connect to any internet service at all e.g. a simple http request? Second though, I don't see any package on PyPI called `smtplib`. smtplib itself is part of the standard Python distribution and the only MicroPython versions on PyPI are dummy placeholders. [This](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5278) might be worth a look though.